# Trying to get 2560x1440 resolution

Tags: 12.10, xorg, hardware, display-resolution, monitor

I have this [motherboard](http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=111-IB-E692-KR) and this [monitor](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/consumer/computer-peripherals/monitors/commercial/LS27A850DS/XK?subsubtype=sa650-and-sa850-led&ei=Wq5RUYehE9CihgeykIHoAw&usg=AFQjCNEsSRMSfXTylQ5g0LokbPknnk4zsA&bvm=bv.44158598,d.ZG4).

It is supposed to get 2560x1440 resolution using HDMI 1.4, but i don't know how..

I have a HDMI cable and a DVI-HDMI adapter, I don't know if they support HDMI 1.4 or not..how can I find out? Could that be the problem?

**EDIT** after Hennes' comment and answer: I have just bought a HDMI to DVI-D (Dual link), and have run:

```
xrandr | grep maximum &
sleep 2
gtf 2560 1440 60.0 &
sleep 2
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00" 311.83  2560 2744 3024 3488  1440 1441 1444 1490  -HSync +Vsync &
sleep 2
xrandr --addmode HDMI2 2560x1440_60.00 &
sleep 2
xrandr --output HDMI2 --mode 2560x1440_60.00 &
exit 0
```

Then I get 2560x1440 but I get this output and everything is pixelated like in the image of the first question of this [thread](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?77594-Problem-with-2560x1440-resolution-via-HDMI):

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 8192 x 8192

  # 2560x1440 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 89.40 kHz; pclk: 311.83 MHz
  Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  311.83  2560 2744 3024 3488  1440 1441 1444 1490  -HSync +Vsync

X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  38
  Current serial number in output stream:  38
```

Note 1: The last five lines are not shown if I run the script in default Ubuntu desktop environment instead of on xfce.

Note 2: The Display manager tag my monitor as "Samsung Electric Company 24" instead of **27**.

Comment: What kind of HDMI-DVI adapter? Is the DVI part single or dual link ?

Comment: @Hennes The adapter is DVI-D (Single link)

Comment: I do not understands why that did not work. Do you have the same problem when you try to use the display port connectors? (Accoring to the links you provided both motherboard and monitor have DP).

Comment: @Hennes http://communities.intel.com/thread/30360

Comment: Drat. Ah well, at least we know the answer.  Pasting it here for future reference.   "Intel graphics does not support dual-link, therefore 1920x1200 is the maximum for DVI and HDMI, 2560x1440 is only possible with a displayport port. "

Answer (score 1):

In a chain of cables and connectors you are limited to the lowest bandwidth of the lowestpart.

In the case of [DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) **single link** that bandwidth means a maximum resolution of 1920 x 1200 at 60 Hz.

Comment: I have just bought a HDMI to DVI-D (Dual link) cable but I don't have more resolutions than before.

Answer (score 0):

I know the command line is easy but you can just use the settings menu as well
Someone asked the same question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189246/how-set-my-monitor-resolution) you can try to use the settings or the given commands at the bottom of the post.

---Edit---
 I just read that your computer doesn't recognise the monitor right, you might want to try and change port or maybe some graphics drivers have to be updated, also I'd reccomand check if the display needs some kind of driver. I know it sounds weird, but a friend of mine  had a problem with his display till he updated his graphics card.